# Convert negative float to positive in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

How do I convert a negative float (like -4.00) to a positive one (like 4.00)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to flip the number is simply to multiply it by `-1`:

```js
console.log( -4.00 * -1 ); // 4
```

If you're not sure whether the number is positive or negative, and don't want to do any conditional checks, you could instead retrieve the absolute value with [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs):

```js
console.log( Math.abs( 7.25 ) );     // 7.25
console.log( Math.abs( -7.25 ) );    // 7.25
console.log( Math.abs( null )) ;     // 0
console.log( Math.abs( "Hello" ) );  // NaN
console.log( Math.abs( 7.25-10 ) );  // 2.75
```

Note, this will turn `-50.00` into `50` (the decimal places are dropped). If you wish to preserve the precision, you can immediately call [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) on the result:

```js
console.log( Math.abs( -50.00 ).toFixed( 2 ) ); // '50.00'
```

Keep in mind that `toFixed` returns a *String*, and not a *Number*. In order to convert it back to a number safely, you can use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), which will strip-off the precision in some cases, turning `'50.00'` into `50`.

Comment: Good, but in case `50.00` it will lose `.00`. Sometimes it is important.

Comment: If you need the precision, `toFixed` is always available. `Math.abs(-50.00).toFixed(2)` will yield the *string* `50.00`.

Answer (score 1):

Take the absolute value: `Math.abs(-4.00)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to take the absolute value ( Math.abs(x) ) or simply flip the sign ( x * -1.00 )

Answer (score 0):

```
var f=-4.00;

if(f<0)
f=-f;
```

Comment: Downvoting, does'nt need those convolutions, Math.abs() does the same thing simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value to be negative (or want to flip the sign), you just use the `-` operator:

```
n = -n;
```

If you want to get the absolute value (i.e. always return positive regardless of the original sign), use the abs method:

```
n = Math.abs(n);
```

Answer (score -1):

value * -1

..is the simplest way to convert from negative to positive